# iPhone personalized push notification with client id - how?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, token, udid

I'm starting with push notifications on the iPhone.
I've read the documentation and several tutorials.
What I want to do:
My server stores app-settings, stored by the user. Depending on these settings I want to send him a push notification.
**Example:** 
Switch for "Weather warnings" is ON -> send notification to this client
Switch for "Weather warnings" is OFF -> don't send notification to this client

Similar to Facebook, when it lets you know, that someone has posted a message on your board.

How might the server be able to know that "token XYZ" matches to "clientId XYZ"?

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Use device UDID as key and then bind to it PUSH token for device. With HTTP request you will send UDID+token pairs and store them on server. When user on device changes it's settings, you send them with device UDID on server.